# FOSUserbundle repositoryClass

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am trying to add repository class for User class that implements BaseClass from FOSUserbundle

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="mdm_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AuthBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser

/**
 * Class UserRepository
 * @package AuthBundle\Repository
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
```

But when clearing cache I get error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                        
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in /.../app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 385 and defined
```

I am trying to implement ApiKeyAuthenticator ([from example in symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html)) but use FOSUserBundle for User Class management and Authentication

## UPDATE

Services:

```
api_key_user_provider:
    class: AuthBundle\Repository\UserRepository

apikey_authenticator:
    class:     AuthBundle\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
    arguments: ["@api_key_user_provider"]
```

Comment: A service has been defined without arguments. How have you defined your services?

Comment: Updated question, provided services.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository constructor requires 2 arguments: $em (EntityManager) and $class (ClassMetadata). Thus, if you want to create a custom doctrine repository as a service, you should declare like:

```
services:
    acme_customer.customer_repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - Acme\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer
```

For more info, check this link http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/